# Unexpected compilation with SASS media queries within a mixin

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, vaadin

I'm currently working on some front-end code for a Vaadin project. I'm trying to get some responsive styling up and running. Unfortunately Vaadin's build in responsive add-on [does not have support for  IE11](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-responsive).

So I want to use media queries to do the responsive design. I've got two SASS files: commontheme.scss is  all the common styling and mymixin.scss contain all desktop specific styling.

So here is my code:

```
@import "../commontheme/commontheme.scss";  //the common them. The common theme

@mixin mymixin
{
    @include commontheme; //Including the stuff from the common theme.

    $small-size: 100px;
    $med-size: 200px;

    @media (max-width:500px)
    {
        .my-image
        {
            width: $small-size;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width:501px)
    {
        .my-image
        {
            width: $med-size;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles to the following CSS:

```
.mymixin
{
    @media (max-width:500px)
    {
        .my-image
        {
            width: 100px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width:501px)
    {
        .my-image
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas what I need is the following code, which works fine if I live edit out the offending lines at the start and end of the block in the compiled CSS.

```
@media (max-width:500px)
{
    .my-image
    {
        width: 100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:501px)
{
    .my-image
    {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

I'm new to this entire development stack. So I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong somewhere, but I haven't had any luck fixing it. If anyone here can offer some insight or a direction to look into I would greatly appreciate it.

For reference, I am using Vaadin 7.2.3 which should include full SASS support.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Sass (see: http://sassmeister.com/gist/fa94eb844ee63e2c3a7b).  In the future, please make sure your code can compile as is (undefined mixins, unavailable imports, etc.).

Comment: The responsive addon actually works in IE11 like a charm. Use it, because I think normal CSS media queries are not that what you want. With CSS you can't declare a breakpoint when e.g. the parent component of you responsive component gets too small/wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just put `@media` tags out of mymixin like that:

```
$myVar: 100px;
@mixin mymixin
{
    @include commontheme; //Including the stuff from the common theme.
    .my-image
    {
        width: $myVar;
    }
}

$myVar: 50px;
@media (max-width:500px)
{
    .mymixin
    {
        .my-image
        {
            width: $myVar;
        }
    }
}
```

You will probably add @media mixins in separate .scss file and include it in main myTheme.scss, but the file structure concpet is not the part of this question.